# Prove that $F'(x)=f(x)$, for almost all $x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a real-valued Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$. Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$.

Prove that $F'(x)=f(x)$, for almost all $x\in[0,1]$.

If it's continuous, then certainly Riemann so linearity holds (I can move things in). Since continuous, I can use the definition ($\epsilon,\delta$ definition) to prove the statement is true.

From the problem, it says "for almost all", so I guess I need to consider Lebesgue. Since Riemann then certainly Lebesgue. However, I'm still stuck...

Comment: Prove that Riemann integrable on $[0,1] $ implies continuous at almost all $x\in [0,1] $.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: Add an answer?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima If given "continuous" instead of "Riemann", then I can show the result is true by starting with the definition of limit. But now given Riemann, so continuous almost everywhere, but can I still use the definition of limits? how? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a simple proof. If you know that $f$ is continuous, then by the FTC, $F$ is differentiable and $F'=f$. So clearly it is important here that $f$ not be continuous. This statement is reminiscent of Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability: integrable iff bounded and continuous almost everywhere. If you know that, then you know that, then the result follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an answer or a comment. By Lebesgue's biconditional criterion for Riemann integrability, a function is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the function $F$ is differentiable at each point where $f$ is continuous, and at these points, $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: How can I combine those two statements together?

Comment: You already know that $f$ is integrable, so it is continuous a.e. Then by the FTC, $F'(x)'=f(x)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: $F'(x)=f(x)$ only at the point where $f$ is continuous at. Since This is true by "continuous almost everywhere," the result follows. However, it feels like I need to add more details. Is there anything I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: Looks complete to me. The result follows almost immediately as long as you are allowed to use this theorem.

Comment: ok. Thank you! Is there possibly another way to prove this?